# Un-Routed Net Constraint in Altium

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I'm new to Altium, and trying to do a simple design, that doesn't do anything :)

Anyway, after running DRC (Design Rule Check) I got "Un-Routed Net Constraint Violation" on some pads and components, this one is really annoying and couldn't solve out after nearly 24 hours.

[image]

Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

Comment: Check the net name on the blue trace - is it the same as on the component pads?  Also, there seems to be a problem on pin 2 of the Reg1 component.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your help! The name on the blue trace +3.3V, the same as on the pads.
About pin2 of the Reg1, yes it has a problem, in fact all three pins of this regulator have the same problem, **Un-Routed Net Constraint Violation**

Comment: Shelve the polygon, remove the blue trace (unroute connection) and try manually routing the blue trace again.

Comment: HI @SpehroPefhany, thanks for your help! I shelved the polygon and rewired that wire in bottom layer, same problem appeared
But if I wired it in the top layer, this what change

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C91s0CaQ-RHzhVpxILqux2ybyqugMU7y/view?usp=sharing

I mean, the constraint will move to the pad itself rather than that long white line

Comment: Looks like something wonky with that regulator footprint or something that is being hidden by it. You can go into single layer mode and look at the layers or just move the regulator down and left to a free area of the board.

Comment: There's something I can't understand here, all pins of this regulator have constraint violations! The GND isn't a problem because I removed the GND polygon for now

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1PnR6x2-c2KpCXTG1a2MNA-VDdjcdPQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally! I figure it out :)
I found 3 warnings, but I didn't take a look at them, I delayed them until I finish the constraints, but the warnings are clear! It says: through hole pads are not plated.
I check the plated property in pad's properties and yes! **It worked!**

Thanks to everyone who helped and intended to

Comment: That will do it. +1

Comment: Ergophobia - Hi, Thanks for coming back with the answer to your question. In order to effectively mark the topic as solved, please consider "[accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" your answer, unless a better one is written (click the "tick mark" next to that answer, to turn it green). That shows that you don't need more help and future readers can quickly see that this was the confirmed solution. Since [you must wait 48 hours after you asked the question](/help/self-answer) before you can accept your own answer, you can accept it any time after 17:45 UTC tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: This was indeed the solution I would have suggested, had you not already discovered it! This very problem has bitten me a few times in the past, and I have learned from those mistakes. Great job finding the issue! +1

Comment: @DerStrom8 The solution never cam to my mind since the component (Regulator) was made ready from my tutor XD. Appreciate your kind words!